# CSV bulk import in Drupal 7 (performance issue)

Tags: performance, csv, drupal, entities, bulk-import

I want to bulk import CSV data to Drupal 7. Here is the scenario:

- I am using 3 entities to combine and form a 4th entity;
- I have to perform CRUD operation with this CSV import;

The process is slowing down with time: there are around 18000 records in the CSV, and this number may increase in the future.

How can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I do this a lot, here's how I handle it

1. Transform the CSV into XML using PHP scripts.
2. Use FEEDS and Feeds Xpath Parser to import in the cleaned up data to Drupal entities, may not be in a single import. You'll have to work out the dependencies and order to import them in as result.

I can't give a more complete answer without knowing exactly how your 3 entities are related to the other (simple EntityReferences or more complicate?) .

Comment: I am using the node reference field type to form the 4th entity. 4th entity is just a combination of first three entities of 3 different  content types.